# Should I upload unfinished work to arxiv or other similar platforms?

Tags: arxiv

My company is currently struggling and I might get fired because of it (throught no fault of mine). I did my Ph.D. in this company a few years ago, which they financed (in part), and during which I produced unpublished research work. This work is mostly unfinished, but I still did write up some notes at the time, even though they are not as well-written as an actual published article. They mostly consist in more or less well organised thoughts, small theorems, ideas etc ... I did try to give them enough of a structure so that they might be read by someone other than me.

Now that the company has financial problems, my boss, who was my adviser at the time of my Ph.D., suggests I upload all of my work to platforms like researchgate or arxiv, including preprints of published work, and any unpublished work as well. There is no copyright problem in doing so. His motivation is that he thinks this will look better on my CV.

My question is the following: Are arxiv / researchgate really the right place for this kind of work? Should I upload my unfinished work to those platforms?

Thanks for sharing any kind of thoughts / input / relevant personal experience.

Comment: Is your boss also the company IP lawyer? If not, seek them out.

Comment: Noted. Are there any concerns besides legal ones?

Comment: @G.Fougeron So far as I am aware, the bar is set very low for what can be uploaded to the arXiv, which is primarily for preprints of papers in mathematics and related subjects. None of it has to be peer-reviewed to be uploaded, so in theory you could upload anything.

Comment: Are there any potential coauthors involved that you would have to ask permission from? This is in the general realm of 'publication' after all.

Comment: Is there any way you could finish the reserach? No matter where it goes, finished work looks a lot better than ambitions.  Finished research might even get published in a journal. Possibly in addition to arxiv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider very carefully what state the work is in and whether you are able (have the skills, facilities **and time**) to improve it later.

Emotionally it may feel as though seizing this opportunity to share your knowledge, however it gets presented, is the right thing to do, but bear in mind that making it publicly available is an irrevocable act - Figshare (at least) make this explicit during the publication process. Right now the situation of "legally" releasing material from a soon-to-close company may justify a rush to publish half-written papers, but this context will no longer be obvious in the future: how will you feel about having this material in circulation under your name when looking for a job in five years' time?

I think it's entirely reasonable to self-publish sub-journal-quality technical reports this way, and you can include some background info or a work-in-progress status in the rubric, but ultimately you must be able to get the works into a state that you are happy with long-term.

(To stress, the difference between this and Lodinn's answer is that you need to think about how this will look in the far future, not just during your upcoming job search.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would say

**do not upload it as-is**

but do

**get it to a minimally published state and submit as soon as possible.**

Your boss has greenlit the publication - that is favorable. But from the context of your question, I get an impression you are only allowed to do that while you still work there. Even if not, both you and advisor might move on, should you get fired, leaving you in a much worse spot for a publication.

I have been working in the industry for a while, and we (culturally) approach ethics and IP protection quite lax compared to many other countries. Yet, even by those lax standards the suggestion to take what potentially constitutes IP the company has paid for and get it accessible to everyone as one is about to get fired sounds incredibly shady to me. Would having more projects under your belt look better on your CV? Most surely, but first make sure you understand what you can and can not disclose during the interviews. But you know what would definitely look bad on your CV? Dealing behind the company's back, getting away with information and no option nor intent to publish it to the company's benefit.

IANAL, but from the management point of view, if you publish it, it becomes an asset for the company. If you upload it to arXiv or post on your personal blog, not so much: these things are more volatile and odds are I would need to reach out to you to do anything with that body of work. Good for you, not good for the company.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer Lodinn :-)